# How we can assign any name to our collator?

Tags: parachain-collator

Is it possible to give the name to the collator so that public can see that the particular collator is of which person or entity.

if yes. How we can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on where you want to see the name. If you are speaking of telemetry you can do this via `--name my-cool-collator`. If you are speaking about on chain it depends on the configuration of the chain. If the chain has the identity pallet, you can set an identity for your on chain account and then people can see the identity on chain.